# Media player that will show list all videos in a folder with a PVR / DVR like interface

Tags: windows, video, media-player

I recently ripped movies from my DVD collection and have it neatly organized in a folder on my Windows desktop. Is there any media that will list out all the videos in that folder, movie poster and the movie's synopsis similar with a DVR / PVR-like interface?

Additional details: all my videos are in MP4 format and my desktop is a Windows 7 Home Premium.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations. Please do explain what you means with "DVR / PVR-like interface" for thoose who don't know the terms.

Answer (score 1):

[XBMC](http://xbmc.org/download/) and [Plex](https://plex.tv/) are two great ones.

Both are forked from the same code base, with XBMC being the "original," I think.

They can access files of almost any format, automatically retrieve the metadata and more, and it all works in a fantastic interface suitable for Keyboard/Mouse, Gamepad, or Remote Controls.

Comment: Do those have a P/DVR like interface?

Comment: In my experience, yes. I use both Plex and XBMC on a regular basis, and my grandmother, who is used to using a DVR from Dish Network (Sorry, I don't know the models) even told me that this is very similar. Also, if you install the proper plugins, I understand that you can even use it AS a DVR. There are several different layouts available, but here is an [example of one](http://www.byterevel.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/Plex-Movie-Page.png)

Answer (score 0):

[Smovault](http://smovault.blogspot.com/p/features.html) is a software that you are looking for exactly.
It is *free* for personal use.
It uses [TMDb](https://www.themoviedb.org/) to download movie data like cast, crew, posters, etc and also provides movie recommendations based on your taste.
It has a bulk import feature which requires folders to be named similar to a movie, which it then searches for correct movie match on TMDb. It does all of this in a user friendly manner.

[DISCLOSURE] - I am the developer of Smovault.